# TouchAnchorId not exactly of OnSwipe in MotionLayout android

Tags: android, animation

I make some code that drag the view in the right, but not working exactly, here is the error:
[Screenshot here](https://s5.gifyu.com/images/Nov-04-2019-17-33-41.gif)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/stream_motion">
<View
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

My Transition:

```
<Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/button"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="right"
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight" />
        <OnSwipe />
    </Transition>
```

I can drag to the right in the button view.